# How to design autostart application that runs as admin on Windows Vista/7?

Tags: c#, .net, uac, autostart

I have the need for my application to start and stop Windows Services based on certain events. The thing is that this application needs to run as an elevated normal user (In order to stop services), as well as auto start when Windows starts. Additionally, it need to be in the systray with an user interface.

What are my options here?
I suppose that there are at least two possibillities:

1. To make the application auto start by putting it in the Startup folder or in the ..\Run key in the registry. But the question is, can this be done without the UAC prompt dialog pops up every time Windows starts?
2. Develop a Windows Service that is installed to run as system, with a separate GUI app in the sys tray. But what are the IPC prossibilities I have here in order to communicate between the elevated service and the normal sys tray app?

Any thoughts and recommendations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely go with option 2 and specifically use WCF (Windows Communication Foundation) to communicate with the Windows Service using wsHTTPS binding so that you can authenticate that the logged in user is allowed to perform the actions on the WCF Service hosted by the Windows Service.

Comment: Yes, I think that this is the best solution for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For number 1, in order to run your application with administrator permissions, then it is impossible to run it without the UAC dialog poping up, or you having the administrator password

For number 2, this is an interesting topic, there is a good article here, with examples & source codes: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/process_communication.aspx the topic is .net remoting. im sure that is the best way to communicate between the different apps.

Answer (score 0):

Actually with number 1 you can chain a couple processes together to achieve an elevated process without a UAC dialog. Like this

First Process-> Launch as Administrator (will need a way to supply credentials) -> launch another process using [ShellExecute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762153(VS.85).aspx) and supplying the Runas verb. -> Your final process

Comment: aren't elevated privileges carried on when the elevated app launches another exe anyway? it goes on without numeric limit, in my experience and from what i have read anyway, you dont need to supply anything in the shell() command, just the next exe full path and the next (new) exe runs with the same privileges as the previous one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Scheduled Tasks facility to accomplish what you want. For scheduling there is an option to schedule a program to run whenever a user logs on. There are options for running the task with alternate credentials.

I couldn't tell you how to set this up programatically (there's probably a WMI interface for it) but it's easy to do through the UI.

Comment: i like this option the best, never could understand why UAC privileges arent remembered for the next run of the same exe, yet you can do it through scheduler, so what was the point of making life harder for everyone while they've left a backdoor open through scheduler? oh of course, the $ they make from selling digital certificates which get your apps auto elevated to admin privileges without a dialog popping up (ever). it will cost your mastercard almost $1,000 - wonder how much of it MicroShaft gets? Why else would they do something so design-flawed? One backdoor only, and its hacky!