# Wix Installer that autostarts exe as admin on winstartup without showing the admin prompt

Tags: c#, fonts, installation, wix, uac

I am making an auto font installer, and got some issues making the setup, first some info about the app. The app is scan a dir (her download dir) every 1 sec. If there are new font files, then I copy them to a backup dir, and install them. To install the font I do basicly 2 things: First copy to a special windows dir for fonts. Then Add a regedit key to the register to finalise the font installation. HOWEVER for the 2nd part the application requires admin rights. So I added a manifest file to the project etc and now when you start the app you get a prompt to run as admin so it all works perfectly.

Now I am making an setup with wix. (Wix is totaly new to me) 
But here is the issue:

I want the exe to be ran everytime the pc starts. I ve googled and found the solution to add the path in the regedit which I did with wix. BUT IT DOESN T WORK. After some more googleing I figurued out that it is because the app requires admin "powers" and thus it doesn t start. Anyone know how I can let wix auto start the exe as admin every time the PC startup. (without the prompt aswell)
The best thing I ve found is to use the CMD to add a windowed scheduled task like:

```
schtasks /create /sc onlogon /tn AutoStartAFI /rl highest /tr "C:\Program Files (x86)\Auto Font Installer\AutoFontInstaller.exe"
```

But I am not certain or I like to make a schedule for it, (but I use the highest parameter so it automaticly got admin rights to execute the app.

Comment: What is wrong with a scheduled task? It seems to be a reasonable solution. A simple exe needs admin rights everytime it is launched - this behavior WILL not change.
Alternatively, you could design your program as a windows service

Comment: but as windows service then I ll need 2 projects, since windows service can t have a UI? And the app requires a tray icon (atleast how I made it :))

Comment: Yes, you would need a service AND a GUi-App.
Look at this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2336249/how-to-design-autostart-application-that-runs-as-admin-on-windows-vista-7?rq=1