# how to start always a wpf app with admin privileges when the os windows start

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, startup, wix3.7

summary I have a wpf app that is locking the window and I want to entry a password from the user who will entry password to my form with mouse click (or read the QR code with mobile phone). because of that the user must not kill the app from the task manager or with any shortcuts.

I researched a lot of but didn't find out any exact solution. I want to do that the user must grant admin rights to the app when installing. And the app automatically will start with admin rights when windows start. because the app needs to disable task manager at runtime by editing regedit. when the lock screen opened, again task manager will be enabled

```
RegistryKey objRegistryKey = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(
            @"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System");
            if (objRegistryKey.GetValue("DisableTaskMgr") == null)
                objRegistryKey.SetValue("DisableTaskMgr", "1");
            else
                objRegistryKey.DeleteValue("DisableTaskMgr");
            objRegistryKey.Close();
```

is it possible ? if not what can I do other. should I use a windows service ?.

I use wix installer for setup.

Comment: It depends. There are two approaches. One where you require the admin credentials to register the app with admin rights, and the other to request the user to allow it to run as Admin. Which is the one you want?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to design autostart application that runs as admin on Windows Vista/7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2336249/how-to-design-autostart-application-that-runs-as-admin-on-windows-vista-7)

Comment: @LupuSilviu the first I want to do

Comment: Maybe this will help https://superuser.com/questions/920697/how-to-run-a-program-with-administrator-privileges-on-user-login-under-windows/1041138#1041138

Comment: @DanielFilipov I don't want to show UAC prompt every starting. the app will  receive admin rights on step of the installation and doesn't need again to ask. I guess it is not possible. I will try lupu silviu's answer but it is not exactly my wanting

Comment: @DanielFilipov I think the accepted and highest voted answer to that question is worth considering. https://superuser.com/a/920708

Comment: @TomBlodget I agree but it was not working for some reason in my case.

Comment: Hope this isn't a virus ;-)

Comment: You can sure that is not a virus :) I explained a bit above what it is. Already the setup will need to admin grant . No one gives the admin rights if doesn't trust it

Answer (score 0):

You could try this approach here, that uses Window API to make the login using a set of known credentials.

This approach should be placed at startup, before you do anything else.

[LogonUser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsimpersonationcontext.aspx)